# Flexbox -display: flex - My contents appear in one line

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am learning flexbox now and I ran into a problem.
I wanted to add two pharagraphs to my boxes but the pharagraphs appear in the same line and the two became one?
Why did it happen? display: flex puts the contents in one line?
I tried flex-direction: column for .boxes1 (and created to .boxes1 within .mainbox1, it worked but want to know a solution for the abovementioned issue.

```css
.mainbox1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #00a400;
  color: #00a400;


}

.boxes1 {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex: 1;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainbox1">

      <div class="boxes1">
        <p>KALUKA</p>
        <p>AKULA</p>
      </div>

      <div class="boxes1">
        <p>KALUKA</p>
        <p>AKULA</p>
      </div>
      
 </div>
```

Comment: do you need boxes 1 to be display flex?

Comment: by default flex box direction is row, so if you put contents inside a flex-box container it would lay out everything from left to right, https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ can be useful for you to learn how it works

Comment: I think I know the other way without display flex but was curious about how to achieve the same thing with it. Thank you. Thank you for the link @Jismon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`display: flex` always shrink elements as hard as possible before pushing them to next line.

Thing you forgot is `flex-wrap: wrap` and `width: 100%` for `p` elements. Making so achieves your desired effect (solution 1).

Another approach (solution 2) is to use `flex-direction: column` for `boxes1`.

If you are new to flexbox I recommend [this guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

#### Solution 1

```css
.mainbox1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #00a400;
  color: #00a400;
}

.boxes1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex: 1;
  height: 100px;
}

.boxes1 p {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainbox1">

  <div class="boxes1">
    <p>KALUKA</p>
    <p>AKULA</p>
  </div>

  <div class="boxes1">
    <p>KALUKA</p>
    <p>AKULA</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

#### Solution 2

```css
.mainbox1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #00a400;
  color: #00a400;
}

.boxes1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex: 1;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainbox1">

  <div class="boxes1">
    <p>KALUKA</p>
    <p>AKULA</p>
  </div>

  <div class="boxes1">
    <p>KALUKA</p>
    <p>AKULA</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

By default, `flex` items are in `flex-direction: row` - You will need to add `flex-direction: column` to your `boxes1` class

```css
.mainbox1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #00a400;
  color: #00a400;


}

.boxes1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex: 1;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainbox1">

      <div class="boxes1">
        <p>KALUKA</p>
        <p>AKULA</p>
      </div>

      <div class="boxes1">
        <p>KALUKA</p>
        <p>AKULA</p>
      </div>
      
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need `boxes1` to be `display: flex` then I would just add another div inside the `boxes1` div and place all your content in there.

```css
.mainbox1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #00a400;
  color: #00a400;


}

.boxes1 {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex: 1;
  height: 100px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainbox1">

      <div class="boxes1">
        <div class="box-content">
          <p>KALUKA</p>
          <p>AKULA</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="boxes1">
        <div class="box-content">
          <p>KALUKA</p>
          <p>AKULA</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.mainbox1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #00a400;
  color: #00a400;


}

.boxes1 {
  /* display: flex; remove this! */
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex: 1;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainbox1">

      <div class="boxes1">
        <p>KALUKA</p>
        <p>AKULA</p>
      </div>

      <div class="boxes1">
        <p>KALUKA</p>
        <p>AKULA</p>
      </div>
      
 </div>
```